# dealing low memory in hadoop 3.1.3 in vmware virtual machine ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apache2, ram, 19.10, memory-usage, hadoop

I installed Hadoop on a Ubuntu virtual machine.
I downloaded the source file that means among the releases available on this page https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html  I downloaded 3.1.3 file
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.1.3/hadoop-3.1.3-src.tar.gz
the installation was successful. I got following message 
[image: Hadoop successful installation]
It appears that I have low memory. I have allotted 2 GB of memory for this virtual machine of Ubuntu. If you can see in above screenshot there are many more virtual machines which I intend to use. 
[image: ram of ubuntu 19.10]
I need other virtual machines for various development works. I want to know how should or rather in what range I should increase the memory so that I can work with Hadoop ecosystem on ubuntu 19.10. I plan to do some development work which can be done with single nodes later on I want to work with multiple nodes. I am doing all this on my laptop which has 12 GB RAM.
and I have following virtual machines
1)Ubuntu 19.10 VM
2)Debian 10 VM
3)Windows 10 VM
4)Cloudera Hadoop VM
5)Ubuntu 19.10 (I have installed Hadoop in this VM)

I have given 2 GB to all VMs.
I also want to know as seen in above I get a Hadoop command prompt.
How can I again get it I mean if I power off the machine.
I notice the shell in above images as 
debian@4d943db32085:~/hadoop$

debian is my username configured in Ubuntu 19.10 
I want to know what is this kind of shell that I got above and why is this number debian@4d943db32085 coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increasing size of RAM in VM from 2GB to 4GB solved the problem.